# Runnig k6 load test returns: The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.(mysql)

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, load-testing, dapper, k6

I am trying to run load test on my api .
here is my simple api :

```
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
     


        [HttpGet(Name = "listStation")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<sty>> Get()
        {
            //var query = "SELECT Code,Name,EnglishName,TelCode FROM  `oln_station` where internetShow = 1 order by Name ;";
            //return (await _online2Connection.QueryAsync<List<Station>>(query, null)).ToList();
            using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=***; DATABASE=***; User=***;PASSWORD=***;Min Pool Size=0;default command timeout=0;"))
            {
                db.Open();
                var result = await db.QueryAsync<Station>("SELECT Code,Name,EnglishName,TelCode FROM  `oln_station` where internetShow = 1 order by Name ");
                db.Close();
                var stations=result.ToList();
                return stations;
            }
        }
    }
    public class sty
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EnglishName { get; set; }
        public string TelCode { get; set; }
        public int StationTypeCode { get; set; }
        public int ZoneCode { get; set; }

        public bool internalShow { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my load test :

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { check } from "k6";

export const options = {
    vus: 1000,
    iterations: 10000,
};




export default (authToken) => {


    var URL = 'http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast';

    const res = http.get(URL);

  
};
```

but Iget this error :
Connection ID "17654119345585914191", Request ID "80000150-0802-f500-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStreamAsync(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStreamAsync(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.OpenAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.OpenAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.OpenAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.CreateAsync(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.CreateAsync(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnectionAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnectionAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriverAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnectionAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at ottracing.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get() in C:\Users\0019848269\source\repos\ottracing\ottracing\Controllers\WeatherForecastController.cs:line 22
   at lambda_method46(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is rather specific, make sure that your targeted api project when running has an available connection to whatever you have defined in your connection strings.
Most probably there is an issue with your data access not been available to your application while running, if you could share more about the db setup, it might be helpfull for everyone.

Edit:
Make sure your values here are correct and validate that your machine can "see" the server by a ping through cmd or smthing

> using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=***;
> DATABASE=***; User=***;PASSWORD=***;Min Pool Size=0;default command timeout=0;"))

Comment: Thank you for your response.
the application can see the database machine, but when the requests are increased by k6 threads, my application can't response to request

Comment: Then you are reaching a connection issue with the database load. Meaning that if for example you dont have configured "pooled connections" then each request will need a new connection to the db. And if your current db limit is say 200 or 1k open connection, your k6 tests are overwhelming it.
Either check on the backing storage configs or lower the tests up to the point where you can complete them to get a sense of the current workload that the db can handle